# SII suministro informacion AEAT. WebServiceException: class xxx do not have a property of the name NNN

Tags: java, webservice, aeat-sii

IDE : NetBeans 8.2
He creado el cliente SOAP sin problemas para el servicio SuministroFactEmitidas.
Cuando intento instanciar el port para una consulta :

```
  private static void pruebaConsulta(){
    https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiService service = new https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiService();
    System.out.println("he instanciado el service");
    https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiSOAP port = service.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas();
    System.out.println("he instanciado el port");

}
```

obtengo el error siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.respuestasuministro.RespuestaLRFEmitidasType do not have a property of the name {https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd}Cabecera
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.<init>(ResponseBuilder.java:616)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.buildResponseBuilder(StubHandler.java:173)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.<init>(StubHandler.java:157)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.initStubHandlers(DatabindingImpl.java:145)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:90)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:59)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:43)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:105)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:875)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:892)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:855)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:435)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
at https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiService.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas(SiiService.java:94)
at prueba.ws.PruebaWs.pruebaConsulta(PruebaWs.java:40)
at prueba.ws.PruebaWs.main(PruebaWs.java:23)
```

Caused by:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: {https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd}Cabecera is not a valid property on class https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.respuestasuministro.RespuestaLRFEmitidasType
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:934)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextWrapper.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBRIContextWrapper.java:106)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.<init>(ResponseBuilder.java:606)
... 17 more
```

No he metido nada de código mío. Todo lo usado lo proporciona el asistente de Netbeans, que ha generado su código a partir del WSDL del servicio.

¿Alguien puede darme una pista de qué pasa con el asistente?

¿Hay que añadir algún parámetro al wsimport?

Comment: Menos mal, llevo un mes con este error y me daba la sensación que era el único al que le pasaba. He enviado un mail a la AEAT, si me aclaran algo al respecto, lo publico.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema (y otros) los tuve yo también cuando empecé a hacer pruebas con el webservice del SII. Está claro que el código que genera automáticamente el Netbeans (o en mi caso el Eclipse) no es del todo correcto.

Por mi parte, la mejor solución que encontré fue utilizar la herramienta `wsimport` que se encuentra en la carpeta `$JDK/bin` de la siguiente manera:

```
wsimport -b bindings.xml -Xnocompile https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl
```

Donde el fichero `bindings.xml` contiene lo siguiente:

```
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

He leído que hay otras alternativas para parsear y generar código para un wsdl entre otros:

- Apache cxf
- Apache Axis 2 (el 1 parece estar abandonado)

Sin embargo son jars bastante pesados (+20Megas) y de momento no quiero usarlos.

Comment: Como no me deja comentar las respuestas de otros usuarios, lo pongo aquí. @dforleans está en lo cierto, ahora el mensaje SOAP ya sale hacia fuera. Me da un error Unsupported Content-Type: text/html Supported ones are: [text/xml] que tiene pinta de ser debido a que aún no tengo el certificado

Answer (score 0):

Habéis solucionado este problema?

Yo en la version 0.6 me funciono sin problemas y ahora al cambiar a la 0.7 me da el error.

Pongo el código que tengo y el error que me da.

```
-- Code --
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "firma.pfx");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pass");

SiiService service = new SiiService();
SiiSOAP siiSOAP = service.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas();

-- Error -- 
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.respuestasuministro.RespuestaLRFEmitidasType do not have a property of the name {https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd}Cabecera
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.<init>(ResponseBuilder.java:511)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIMethodHandler.buildResponseBuilder(SEIMethodHandler.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.<init>(SyncMethodHandler.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:639)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:342)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:324)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:306)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
    at https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiService.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas(SiiService.java:72)
    at Barpimo.Contabilidad.SII.SuministroFacturas.consultaEstadoEmitidas(SuministroFacturas.java:258)
    at Barpimo.Contabilidad.SII.SuministroFacturas.<init>(SuministroFacturas.java:50)
    at aapella.lanzador.<init>(lanzador.java:212)
    at aapella.lanzador$4.run(lanzador.java:1486)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: {https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd}Cabecera is not a valid property on class https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.respuestasuministro.RespuestaLRFEmitidasType
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:942)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.<init>(ResponseBuilder.java:500)
    ... 27 more
```

**SOLUCIONADO**
He vuelto a generar los WebServices y sin problemas.